# REPLACE in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do the following, I want to replace only the first "T_" from a string value.
However with REPLACE, it will replace all the "T_" occurrences

```
REPLACE('T_DEV_ABCT_FACT_SALEST_TEST', 'T_')
```

Is there any other way of doing this so that it replace only and only the first occurrence ?

Thank You,

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex replacement:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 'T_DEV_ABCT_FACT_SALEST_TEST' AS val
)

SELECT val, REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^T_', 'F_') AS val_out
FROM t;

-- T_DEV_ABCT_FACT_SALEST_TEST, F_DEV_ABCT_FACT_SALEST_TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have to replace the "first occurrence" then Tim's will only match "when the occurrence is at the start", luckily [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html) has some options to help with this, the first extra parameter says, only replace 1 instance (the second 1 in this case) and there are some other hack methods like [INSERT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/insert.html)/[POSITION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/position.html) (that don't work so good)

```
SELECT 
    column1 as val
    ,REPLACE(val, 'T_', 'x') as first_try
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '^T_', 'x') AS only_first_token
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(val, 'T_', 'x', 1, 1) AS first_t_only
    ,POSITION('T_', val) as pos
    ,INSERT(val, POSITION('T_', val),iff(POSITION('T_', val) > 0, 2,0), 'x') as insert_hack
FROM VALUES
    ('T_LINE_START_WITH_T'),
    ('LINE_NOT_START_WITH_T'),
    ('LINE_NO_TEE_UNDERSCORE')
    ;
```

gives:

| VAL | FIRST_TRY | ONLY_FIRST_TOKEN | FIRST_T_ONLY | POS | INSERT_HACK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T_LINE_START_WITH_T | xLINE_STARxWITH_T | xLINE_START_WITH_T | xLINE_START_WITH_T | 1 | xLINE_START_WITH_T |
| LINE_NOT_START_WITH_T | LINE_NOxSTARxWITH_T | LINE_NOT_START_WITH_T | LINE_NOxSTART_WITH_T | 8 | LINE_NOxSTART_WITH_T |
| LINE_NO_TEE_UNDERSCORE | LINE_NO_TEE_UNDERSCORE | LINE_NO_TEE_UNDERSCORE | LINE_NO_TEE_UNDERSCORE | 0 | xLINE_NO_TEE_UNDERSCORE |